# WKWebView loaded twice, trying to go back I have to press twice on back navigation button

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I'm trying to show a website using the WKWebView, it works fine as for the internet work.

problem is it is loading the site twice (it seems like it's going to another ViewController).

here is my code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    myWebView = WKWebView()
    myWebView.navigationDelegate = self as? WKNavigationDelegate
    view = myWebView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
    myWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

Comment: I have the same thing. What was the problem?

Comment: any information on this topic? i face the same issue with same load requests

Comment: Did you get any solution?